# IIS routes successfully with independent domains, but not with host heading

Tags: windows, iis

I have a front end website iilseeker.com routed thru a site (frontdomain) with port 80 binding to iilseeker.com in the hosts file and a physical folder "C:\Users\PAG\Documents\Investment Innovation LLC\frontwebsite" which holds the published code for my html front end. Works fine.

The front end takes all incoming traffic and redirects applications to the back end ASP.NET by a URL. I want to use a host header for redirection but it does not work. I have tried backweb.iilseeker.com in hosts bound to a site (backdomain) with port 81 and a physical folder "C:\Users\PAG\Documents\Investment Innovation LLC\backwebsite".  When I enter http://backweb.iilseeker.com I expected hosts to redirect it to backdomain and thence to backwebsite, but it returns a socket exception with no host found. System is Windows10 with IIS10.

I just read that IIS does not automatically recognize ASP.Net websites: can that be correct and if so how do you enable it? I am on Windows10 and IIS10. 
The solution, for the moment, is to use a different domain name; it maps from hosts to backdomain and thence to backwebsite and runs. Its just slow, and kludgy. I am completely stuck over why backweb.iilseeker.com won't work and would appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

After months of experimentation I used IIS to connect to the site of backdomain and found that I was missing the port number when routing from frontdomain.  Using the URL http://backweb.iilseeker.com:81 solved the problem.

I had read everything possible about the use of IIS sites and the host file but in scores of articles never saw an example that was this explicit.

The names have changed but you can try it on iilseeker.com and select one of the menus "Use correlation" or "Use factors". Internal routing is also significantly faster.